# I am new in BigCommerce Platform. Anyone please tell me a page builder I can use to design my web page on BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am creating a web page first time in BigCommerce. Is there any page builder like we used in WordPress to build pages quickly. Im in a little hurry

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Shogun: https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/shogun-landing-page-builder/

It's a one-click app that provides a drag and drop editor for building pages.